# UNEXPECTED_ERROR when calling wsdl functions

Tags: php, parameters, wsdl

I am trying to call to some wsdl functions from php.

Let's say I have these two functions:

```
**listStyleCategories**
Input:
<xs:complexType name="listStyleCategories">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="arg0" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
Output:
<xs:complexType name="listStyleCategoriesResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="return" type="tns:listStyleCategoriesOutputBean" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="listStyleCategoriesOutputBean">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="categories" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
<xs:element name="statusInfo" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

**listStyleTypes**
Input:
<xs:complexType name="listStyleTypes">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="arg0" type="tns:listStyleTypesInputBean" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="listStyleTypesInputBean">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="category" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="language" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
Output:
<xs:complexType name="listStyleTypesResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="return" type="tns:listStyleTypesOutputBean" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="listStyleTypesOutputBean">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="detail" type="tns:listStyleTypesOutputDetailBean" nillable="true"    minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
<xs:element name="statusInfo" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="listStyleTypesOutputDetailBean">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="icon" type="xs:base64Binary" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="styleId" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="type" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

when I call the first one, which has a single parameter, everything goes ok:

```
$param = array('arg0' =>$language);
$result = $client->listStyleCategories($param);
$result_arr = objectToArray($result);
echo "<pre>";print_r($result_arr);echo "</pre>";
```

But when I call the second function with two parameters, I get an UNEXPECTED_ERROR:

```
$param = array('category' =>'Woman','language'=>$language);
$result = $client->listStyleTypes($param);
$result_arr = objectToArray($result);   
echo "<pre>";print_r($result_arr);echo "</pre>";
```

I know for good that the 'Woman' category, and the defined language are right. Maybe I'm building wrong the parameters?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
$params = array('arg0' => array('category' =>'Woman','language'=>$language));
$result = $client->listStyleTypes($param);
```

Your `listStyleTypes` function is like `listStyleCategories` except that `arg0` is a complex type (hash) of two values.